# Make Eqns inside Conditional Bigger

Tags: conditionals, braces

The code below works, but when LaTex generates the equations, the equations are small and appear "scrunched". How can this code be modified s.t. the equations are at least as big as the term $F(x)$ in the equation?

```
\begin{equation}
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1 - \frac{\theta}{x}^{\alpha}}{1 - \frac{\theta}{T}^{\alpha}} & \text{if}\ a=1 \\
\frac{\log (x / \theta)}{\log(T/\theta)} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cases` environment uses `\textstyle`, not `\displaystyle` The same is valid for `array`, `matrix` and the like.

Load the `mathtools` package, in the place of `amsmath`, and use `dcases`.